# Extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

Tags: magento

I'm new at Magento and stuggling with an issue that seems to me like it should be simple.

I want to override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class and I've created: `app\code\local\Feno\Catalog\Block\Navigation.php` that contains (snippet):

```
class Feno_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $exclude_ids = array())
    {
```

In `app\code\local\Feno\Catalog\etc\config.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <Feno_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Feno_Catalog>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Feno_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

However when I run the page, I get this error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml(Array ...
```

So it isn't even picking up my class..

I tried adding `app\etc\modules\Feno_Catalog.xml` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Feno_Catalog>
         <active>true</active>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Feno_Catalog>
   </modules>
</config>
```

But that doesn't work. Am I forgetting something?

As I said I'm new to Magento, so not sure where to look and Google and stackoverflow havent been able to help. FYI, I use PHPStorm so XML, etc are all valid (IDE checks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here. I put it on hold after I didn't manage previous time and tried again today (cost me a couple of hours) and found it after searching and trying all sort of stuff.

The main issue appeared to be was that the block had to be registered in /app/etc/local.xml

```
...
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Feno_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <install>
        ...
```

After adding this it works perfect!

Found this short and sweet blog post: http://priyasmagento.blogspot.com/2010/07/override-navigation-block.html

Decided to add the blog post content also, the site doesn't seem very well maintained and would be a shame to lose the data. 
© http://priyasmagento.blogspot.com/

1. Create mymodulepack  folder in local folder.

   ```
   Path:   C:\wamp\www\triangeli\app\code\local\mymodulepack
   ```
2. Create catalog folder inside mymodulpack namespace.
3. Create block, etc, helper folder inside Catalog folder.
4. Create Navigation.php file in block folder. Override class and write functions inside this file.

   ```
   <?php

   class mymodulepack_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

   {
     //write the function here,which add new functionality or override the     original code
     public function override()
       {
         //write the code here 
       }  
   }
   ```
5. Create config.xml file inside etc folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
   <config>
     <modules>
       <mymodulepack_Catalog>
         <version>0.1.0</version>
       </mymodulepack_Catalog>
     </modules>
     <global>
       <blocks>
         <catalog>
           <rewrite>
             <class>mymodulepack_Catalog_Block</class>
           </rewrite>
         </catalog>
       </blocks>
       <helpers>
         <catalog>
           <rewrite>
             <class>mymodulepack_Catalog_Helper</class>
           </rewrite>
         </catalog>
       </helpers>
     </global>
   </config>
   ```
6. Create Data.php file inside Helper folder.

   ```
    <?php 
   class mymodulepack_Catalog_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
   { }
   ?>
   ```
7. To “activate” my new module “mymodulepack”: 
   In the file app\etc\local.xml reference mymodulepack under the global scope:

   ```
   <config>
       <global>
           <blocks>
            <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                 <navigation>mymodulepack_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
              </rewrite>
            </catalog>
           </blocks>
           <install>
               <date><![CDATA[Thu, 17 Dec 2009 11:50:52 +0000]]></date>
           </install>
           <crypt>
               <key><![CDATA[d89edae607842ce91b0e36456faed63e]]></key>
           </crypt>
           <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
           <resources>
               <db>
                   <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
               </db>
               <default_setup>
                   <connection>
                       <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                       <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                       <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                       <dbname><![CDATA[pizzaman]]></dbname>
                       <active>1</active>
                   </connection>
               </default_setup>
           </resources>
           <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
       </global>
       <admin>
           <routers>
               <adminhtml>
                   <args>
                       <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                   </args>
               </adminhtml>
           </routers>
       </admin>
   </config>
   ```
8. Disable cache from admin section.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add your new class name in your config.xml file, it should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Feno_Catalog>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Feno_Catalog>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <catalog>
        <class>Feno_Catalog_Helper</class>
      </catalog>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <class>Feno_Catalog_Block</class>
      </catalog>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Feno_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

And you class in app/code/local/Feno/Catalog/Blcok/Catalog/Navigation.php

```
<?php
class Feno_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
}
```

And your helper file(it is optional)

app/code/local/Feno/Catalog/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Feno_Catalog_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Update:**
I forgot something to add. The module name you using **Catalog** is already used by magento core. So you need to change the module name or use `<depends> ..</depends>` tag. Otherwise module conflict may be happen or your module doesn't load. To use depends,

```
<Mage_Catalog>
            <depends>
                <Packagename_Modulename />
            </depends>
</Mage_Catalog>
```

So your Feno_Catalog.xml (app/etc/modules) file should be,

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Feno_Catalog>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
      <depends>
      <Mage_Catalog />
      </depends>
    </Feno_Catalog>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: You should also add a dependency between your module and the Core catalog module (to ensure your config is loaded after the Core).

Comment: @MihaiStancu Oh yes. Thanks, i have updated my answer. please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, so far it's looking good, however I'm now getting this error after adding the Helper: `Class 'Feno_Catalog_Helper_Category_Flat' not found in app\Mage.php`.

Without the helper in the XML, I get a little further, but get stuck on: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php`

Comment: please update your question with that code, so that I can able to check.